# php sidebar and footer inside main

Tags: php, css

I help develop my school's website what I can not figure out is why on a certain page the sidebar and footer go into the table main. It only does this for two thing custodial and kitchen even when I think the code for say administrators is the same code and looks the same to me.

This is the code used to generate the teachers page

The link below will take you to the broken page since I can't post pictures
http://gwhs.kana.k12.wv.us/academics/display.php?action=teacher&id=103

While the link below will take you to one that actually works
http://gwhs.kana.k12.wv.us/academics/display.php?action=teacher&id=24

If you want the entire file for this code let me know and I will post a link

```
function dTeacher() {
        global $db, $id;
        if ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name, department, schedule, education, whyteach, phone, email, image, quote FROM teachers WHERE id = ?"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $res = $stmt->get_result();
            $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();
            $schedule = array();
            $schedule = explode(",",$row['schedule']);
            $education = explode(",",$row['education']);
            $noshow = array(20, 14, 25, 15, 24, 21, 23);
            print '<h1>Viewing '.$row['name'].'\'s Profile!</h1>';
            if ($row['image']) {
                print '<img style="max-width:40%; display: block; margin: 2% auto;" src="'.$row['image'].'" alt="Teacher Image Here">';
            }
            if (!(in_array($row['department'], $noshow))) {
            print '<h3>Schedule</h3>
            <table id="maindata">
                <tr id="head"><td style="width:30%;">Period</td><td style="width:70%;">Class</td></tr>';
                for ($i=0; $i<count($schedule); $i++)
                {
                $oddeven = ($i%2==0) ? "even" : "odd";
                $scnum = $schedule[$i];
                $scresult = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM classes where id = {$scnum} LIMIT 1");
                $scrow = $scresult->fetch_assoc();
                if ($scnum == 1337) {
                $scrow['name'] = "OFF";
                } //off periods
                print '<tr id="'.$oddeven.'"><td style="width:30%;">'.$i.'</td><td style="width:70%;"><a href="/academics/display.php?action=dclass&id='.$scrow['id'].'">'.$scrow['name'].'</a></td></tr>';
                }
            }
            if ($row['education']) {
                print "</table><h3>Education</h3>";
                for ($i=0; $i<count($education); $i++)
                {
                $oddeven = ($i%2==0) ? "even" : "odd";
                print '<table id="maindata"><tr id="'.$oddeven.'"><td>'.$education[$i].'</td></tr>';
                }
                print '</table>';
                }
            if ($row['phone'] || $row['email']) {
                print '
                <h3>Contact</h3>
                <table id="maindata"><tr id="even"><td style="width:30%;">Phone</td><td>'.$row['phone'].'</td></tr>
                <tr id="odd"><td style="width:30%;">Email</td><td>'.$row['email'].'</td></tr></table>';
            }
                if ($row['whyteach'] != "") {
                print '<h3>Why do you teach?</h3>
                <table id="maindata"><tr id="even"><td><p>'.$row['whyteach'].'</p></td></tr></table>';
                }
                if ($row['quote'] != "") {
                print '<h3>Favorite Quote</h3>
                <table id="maindata"><tr id="even"><td><p>'.$row['quote'].'</p></td></tr></table>';
                }
        }
        else {
        print "Error with your request.";
        die();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are not closing this table tag `<table id="maindata">` unless they have eduction data

Comment: Please don't mix PHP and HTML like this. Separate the PHP logic from the html. (One is logic, the other presentation). A really simple template class/function which takes an array of variables, and feeds them to a php file which is HTML code with ```<?= $teacher_name;?>``` for example will help you lots. For example it would have most likely prevented this error! At it's most basic, put all the necessary data into an array with key names, then just ```include 'teacher.tpl.php'``` which is a php file with all the html. it'll allow you to modify the layout so much easier than this mess!

Comment: I did not create this code I am only trying to get it fixed which it is now thanks to you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug here, you are not closing table tag:

```
        if (!(in_array($row['department'], $noshow))) {
        print '<h3>Schedule</h3>
        <table id="maindata">
            <tr id="head"><td style="width:30%;">Period</td><td style="width:70%;">Class</td></tr>';
            for ($i=0; $i<count($schedule); $i++)
            {
                $oddeven = ($i%2==0) ? "even" : "odd";
                $scnum = $schedule[$i];
                $scresult = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM classes where id = {$scnum} LIMIT 1");
                $scrow = $scresult->fetch_assoc();
                if ($scnum == 1337) {
                    $scrow['name'] = "OFF";
                } //off periods
                print '<tr id="'.$oddeven.'"><td style="width:30%;">'.$i.'</td><td style="width:70%;"><a href="/academics/display.php?action=dclass&id='.$scrow['id'].'">'.$scrow['name'].'</a></td></tr>';
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
```

Because of this, when the profile has Schedule the table is not closed and the page will display bad.

And closes it here:

```
if ($row['education']) {
  print "<h3>Education</h3>";
```

With two modifications the web should do its work fine.

Take a look this HTML validator, it will help you:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgwhs.kana.k12.wv.us%2Facademics%2Fdisplay.php%3Faction%3Dteacher%26id%3D103&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Best regards.

Comment: Small tip :Faster to do this with firefox though. Just press alt + u if u have invalid HTML it will be marked red

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Chrome for developing and Firefox for testing, I'll use Firefox to validate my designs. Good tip! ;)

Answer (score 0):

First words: You should re-think the layout. Creating multiple tables to display page content is not the best approach and furthermore IDs have to be unique. So for valid HTML you can't have multiple tables with the ID `maindata`.

As mentioned by [cmorrissey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602732/cmorrissey) in the comments, you're not closing the first table, unless you enter the next `if` statement. Furthermore this part

```
if ($row['education']) {
  print "</table><h3>Education</h3>";
  for ($i=0; $i<count($education); $i++) {
    $oddeven = ($i%2==0) ? "even" : "odd";
    print '<table id="maindata"><tr id="'.$oddeven.'"><td>'.$education[$i].'</td></tr>';
  }
  print '</table>';
}
```

of your code closes the previous `<table id="maindata">` but opens a new one in each iteration of the loop. After the loop, your closing just one of them. So if it is correct, that you want to create multiple of these tables, you should close them in the loop as well:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($education); $i++) {
  $oddeven = ($i%2==0) ? "even" : "odd";
  print '<table id="maindata"><tr id="'.$oddeven.'"><td>'.$education[$i].'</td></tr>';
  print '</table>';
}
```

Comment: So what would happen if I were to start maindata before department and end it at the bottom of the function while remove the others

Comment: Then you would have one table. Everything in between should be added as a row and you can't use `h3` in between unless they're wrapped in a `td`